# Java Hibernate Multithread

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, hibernate, playframework

I have the following method in a singleton object that was run in multithreaded environment (`Play 2 Java`, `MySQL`, `Hibernate`):

```
@Transactional
void deleteItem(int itemId, int userId) {
  .....
  synchronized(this) {
    if(getItemCount(userId) < 2) { // go to database to get the count
      return;
    }

    if(!userOwnItem(itemId, userId) {  // check if item belongs to user
      return;
    }

    delete(itemId); // go to db to delete the item
  }
  ....
}
```

I am having a hard time understanding why occasionally it goes below 1 when run concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is not static, So your synchronization locks on the current object only `synchronized(this)`.

I suppose this method is not from the singleton object, so you could have like 4 this objects at the same time (4 client connects on the 4 different threads in async calls) and 3 of them calls 'deleteItem' .... and you got -3 in a moment.

You need to synchronize on the class `synchronize(MyDb.class)` or convert this object to singleton.

Comment: This is actually method from a singleton object. sorry i did not mention it